# Node.js serves "index of /"

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js

I've been experimenting with Node.js on my windows machine and also my linux machine to create a web server using node.

If I try my code on windows and activate my server with "node server.js" and navigate to localhost:8080 I am met with "Hello World!" as intended.

But if I try on my linux box with the same code it shows me the directory instead of serving the page. Not sure what's going on here!

Here's the code I've been using

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8080, 'localhost');
console.log('Server running at http://localhost:8080/');
```

I've tried using my local ip to the machine and also using the domain followed by ":8080", both give me the same results.

I cant find anybody else with the same problem and I've been looking for hours.

[image: indexof]

Comment: `ecstatic server running @ 192.168.1.90:8080` It seems that you've tried to connect to some other address where this thing is running. Have you really tried `localhost:8080`?

Comment: doesn't node crash when you run your js file?

Comment: I should mention that it's a folder in the root folder "/node".
Nope, nothing crashes, works as normal and I get the console log response

Comment: If you're getting a directory listing, then some other server is responding to your request, not the node server.  Your node code in server.js is not capable of providing a directory listing so it is not that code doing it.

Comment: I've disabled apache and tried it out there and it still lists my directory

Comment: Try changing the port. Then you'll know for sure if it's another server.

Comment: You can run `sudo netstat -lpnt` on your linux box to see what listeners there are on that machine to see what else is listening to your 8080 port. Also, when you say "navigate to localhost:8080" are you talking about a web browser on that computer?

Comment: tried changing ports and 'netstat -lpn' doesn't list anything that's using 8080 :/

Comment: On my windows PC @jfriend00. So I typed in the local ip for the server followed by :8080

Comment: What exactly are you doing on the linux machine when you get the directory listing.  What exactly are you typing and what program are you typing that into?  If you're going to use `localhost:8080`, you will need to be typing that into a web browser that is running on the Linux machine.

Comment: I run it using "node server.js" on my linux machine. Then on my windows mahcine I open firefox and type in "192.168.1.90:8080" and that's where I get the directory listing

Comment: @jfriend00
Just tried it on a different windows computer and now it's doing the same thing as it is with my linux pc.
Installed node, installed http-server, run it and I'm met with the index thing again

Comment: Did you run the netstat command on your linux box that I suggested above?  That will tell you what servers are running on the linux box and what ports they are listening to.  And, are you 100% sure that `192.168.1.90` is the linux box?

Comment: Yes I ran that command, nothing came up as using port 8080.
Yes absolutely

Comment: Nothing?  It should have at least shown your server.  If nothing else is listening to the 8080 port, then I'd wonder if that computer is configured for port forwarding from 8080 to some other port/server or if you have the wrong IP address for your request and you aren't actually connection to your Linux box.  I promise you that your server.js as shown is not capable of creating that directory listing.  There simply isn't code to make that type of response.

Comment: It's strange, I'm a windows PC at the moment, WAMP isn't running so I know apache can't be doing it.
If I run "node server.js" then the desired output is on my browser.
If I type in "http-server" which is a module for node, then I get the directory browsing

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue while manually starting server from windows machine.
using command http-server -p 4200

Say, I was trying to start the server from D:/ProjectName. When I changed that and started from D:/ProjectName/build, it was working fine. Build folder has the index file and all other files.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow.  I cannot tell if this is supposed to be an answer to the original question (in 2016), or if you have a question about your own problems.  If you have a question and the solutions here do not resolve it, consider asking a new question.